# unit testing private class within a public class?

Tags: unit-testing

Is it possible to unit test a private class? I have something like

```
     public class ClassA: ClassB    
      {     
         private class ClassX: ClassY   
         { 
            public static int TestMethod(int numberA, int numberB) 
               { 
               return numberA + numberB
               }  
          }
       }
```

I'd like to test the "TestMethod" but can't access it. I tried to create new instance for the private ClassX using Class A and Class Y but it won't let me access the "TestMethod"

Comment: What language is this? It looks like C# or Java, but it is invalid in both.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to test private members. They should be tested using pubic exposed members.

However, If you are using [MSTest](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mstest), You can use [accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184807%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If you are using other test frameworks, you can leverage [reflection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesnewkirk/archive/2004/06/07/150361.aspx).

The above are applicable in .NET. I have no idea how to achieve the same in other languages (in case you are asking for java/other language).

Answer (score 1):

There should be a public method somewhere that calls the method in your private class.  You should unit test that method.  If you can't get to your private method through a public interface, then there is probably no need for the private method to begin with.